# move div to different section when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that displays on the left side a product image. I have also on the right side, multiple check-boxes next to customer addresses.
Example:

```
<div section visible>
  <div>image/product 1</div>  <div>cb-1-address - cb-2-address - cb-3-address</div>
  <div>image/product 2</div>  <div>cb-1-address - cb-2-address - cb-3-address</div>
  <div>image/product 3</div>  <div>cb-1-address - cb-2-address - cb-3-address</div>
</div section visible>

<div section hidden></div section hidden>
```

When a product row gets its check-box selected, then the div containing:

Example:

```
<div>image/product 1</div>  <div>cb-1-address CHECKED - cb-2-address - cb-3-address</div>
```

Then the hidden section becomes visible and the row that has the selected checked box gets moved to that section.

Are there any examples/ scripts of how to do this using JQuery that I can be directed too?

For your help, thank you very much.

Comment: Are you freely able to adjust the html mark up? I'd just putting a Fiddle together now.

Comment: Yes, I can adjust the HTML if needed. Many thanks.

Comment: Mine suggestion is give all your HTML tags identity, and using Jquery to locate the tags, then you can do anything you want like copy entire <div> to other place, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/2qay4kqh/4/)

```
$(':checkBox').click(function () {

  var item = $(this).closest('div');

   $('#hiddenArea').append(item.prev()).append(item);    

});
```

I have adjusted the mark up:

```
<div>
 <h1>Visible Products</h1>

<div>image/product 1</div>
<div>cb-1-address - cb-2-address - cb-3-address
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Address 1" />
</div>
<div>image/product 2</div>
<div>cb-1-address - cb-2-address - cb-3-address
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Address 2" />
</div>
<div>image/product 3</div>
<div>cb-1-address - cb-2-address - cb-3-address
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Address 1" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="hiddenArea">
 <h1>Hidden Section</h1>
</div>
```

If you update your question with specific mark up I'd be happy to update the JsFiddle.

Comment: I will begin implementing your code, I have to clean up the HTML and CSS so that I can also post decent markup. Thank you so much Matt. Your help is very kind.

Comment: Anytime. I have updated my answer which includes the use of `.prev()` along with `.closest()` to show ways of grabbing DOM elements which you may not be able to access without a specified id or class attribute.

Comment: Do you know how to add an smooth slide effect to the element when it gets moved from one section to the next?

Comment: Yes, but this should be added as a separate question. If the answer I gave answered your original question sufficiently please mark this as complete (or feel free to await further answers). Then if you add a new question I will gladly answer that one for you. :-)

Comment: That is fair. Thank you. I will try to update this question as soon as possible so I can post a new one.

Comment: @itortu was this answer sufficient? :-)

Comment: Hi Matt. Your answer was very useful. Many thanks :)

Comment: Splendid. As I said before, if you update your question I'll gladly tweak my answer to assist you further.